# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.io' has no attribute 'tf_record_iterator'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

I have a file named as `train00.tfrecord`, I want to read it via tensorflow. So I wrote the following code.

```
frame_lvl_record = "frame-sample/frame/train00.tfrecord"
for example in tf.io.tf_record_iterator(frame_lvl_record):
    print(example)
```

But it returned the following error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_20529/2760031393.py in <module>
----> 1 for example in tf.io.tf_record_iterator(frame_lvl_record):
      2     print(example)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.io' has no attribute 'tf_record_iterator'
```

How can I solve this dependency issue?

Answer (score 4):

'''USE THIS COMMAND TO READ THE TFRecordDataset

```
data=tf.data.TFRecordDataset("filenames")                     
n=10          
for raw_record in data.take(n):                              
    print(repr(raw_record))
```

'''

Comment: Can you please send me the documentation?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord              you can check it here

Comment: For reading the complete dataset, what should I pass as the value of n? `len(data)` is not working

Comment: Should I use 
```for raw_record in data:                              
    print(repr(raw_record)) ```

Comment: use repr() it used to convert data in string type